# Using JMS (ApacheMQ) and Camel for updating multiple GUIs/Visualization

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I need to create a drawing application in Java where a user draws lines and colors among other things on the master application and a number of client viewers update their views accordingly. Each client viewer may visualize the received data differently (for example, given a line drawn in the master application, viewer 1 may do the same while viewer 2 may apply some filtering to show it differenlty.).

Is Java Messaging Service approach a good choice for such an application? The master app would send out the changes in messages and the clients would asynchronously update their views. Later I might need to distingush the types of the data sent out, so was considering CAMEL for setting up different topics for different clients. If these are not a good choice, what technology is out there that's suitable?

Are they still a good choice if later the design changes so that every client also sends out updates and needs to update accordingly?

Will this approach scale out if the update rate/amount in the master application is huge? (for example, 60 frames/sec updates on 1024x768 pixels or more. - I could probably calculate frame difference and send out only the changes.)

Thank you for your time and sorry for the many questions. Please let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong, too.

Answer (score 0):

While it is do-able, I doubt JMS and Camel would be the best fit for this type of distributed application.

JMS/Camel are good for enterprise integration scenarios where you want some level of decoupling between services and consumers. The decoupling usually comes with maintenance and performance overheads.

For the type of app you describe, it sounds like decoupling us not important so you might be better off looking at some distributed application environment where the clients and servers are implemented in the same language and you have rpc calls between them.

Depending on your language choice, distributed technologies you could consider are: distributed Java, distributed Ruby, Celluloid, HTML5+Websockets (e.g. check out meteor.com).